# intellij idea 2016 автоматически удаляет неиспользуемые и неправильные import-ы?

Tags: intellij-idea

Привет знатокам!
Навел курсор на класс, который хотел добавить в Maven, Нахал Alt+Enter, 2 раза стрелкой вниз (думал, что это Add depen. по привычке), но теперь студия скрывает все импорты. ИХ просто не добавляет. Как можно это исправить, товарищи ? 
В настройках Imports ничего нет

Comment: File - Settings - Editor - General - Auto Import покажите, что там есть.

Comment: Та же проблема, только в general нет пункта про import. Подскажите че- нить.

Comment: @Vadim File - Settings  далее по поиску найди Auto Impor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File - Settings - Editor - General - Auto Import 
убирать галочку "Optimize imports on the fly"